# Nobody can solve this puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

Yes, literally, nobody can solve this puzzle.

While every answer might get upvotes, nobody's answer will be accepted.

Nobody gets the green check.

In this sense, the puzzle is fair to everyone.

Let's see if the puzzle gets solved!

---

...Although it doesn't matter that much in the end.

Just for fun! (:

Comment: There are currently four users called Nobody. If one of them answers, will they get the green check? :)

Comment: As I stated in the puzzle, it is fair to everyone (:

Comment: @Jens When I saw the title of this puzzle I was literally going to make a sockpuppet of that name in order to answer it. I shan't bother now that someone else has made the same joke.

Comment: I should add, with my moderator's hat on, that so far as I am currently aware WhatsUp does not have a sockpuppet called Nobody :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan In this sense, the puzzle does have a "smart" solution which doesn't require sockpuppets (-:

Comment: rot13(Ubcrshyyl vg'f abg [gnt:bcra-raqrq] be [gnt:hafbyirq-zlfgrevrf], orpnhfr V jbhyq or ernyyl hcfrg vs gung jrer gb or gur pnfr)

Comment: @Avi I think it is not.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try

Comment: Just to confirm, this question has a *single demonstrably correct solution* that can be deduced directly from the formulation as it is now, right?

Comment: What happens when there are more than 1 Nobody ?

Comment: This question is attracting a lot of nonsense answers, and it's impossible to tell whether any particular "answer" is correct, or even what counts as an attempted answer in the first place. Because of this, I've closed the question as "unclear what you're asking": please edit the question to make it clearer what *type of thing* you're looking for, at the very least.

Comment: @Deusovi It just happened that the correct answer appeared during my sleep, so that I could not accept it immediately... This is indeed an experiment to create a new kind of puzzle, where the useful information of the answer is not directly located in the traditional answer box. And I think all my statements are valid in the end (see accepted answer below).

Comment: I should have made that sockpuppet after all. Anyway, I dispute the statement that the puzzle is fair to everyone. You only get to change your display name once per 30 days; as a moderator and well known user it would be highly inconvenient for me to have to be called "Nobody" for 30 days.

Comment: (I do think it was funny, though.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ah, I didn't know that... I did try changing my display name several times in different communities, and it all worked fine. But now that you mentioned this restriction, I think perhaps that's because I did the changes within very short time. Anyway glad that you had fun!

Comment: There's a special exception for newly created accounts, which you'll have run into.

Comment: In light of the puzzle being closed, I’ve retracted my answer. It was an interesting idea, but unfortunately not as fair as it turned out to be :)

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Ja, sorry for that... I hope this could inspire people for more creative ways of puzzling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, literally, nobody can solve this puzzle.

> My name is Nobody

While every answer might get upvotes, nobody's answer will be accepted.

> This is my answer

Nobody gets the green check.

> I should get the green check when my answer is accepted

In this sense, the puzzle is fair to everyone.

> Anybody can change their display name to "Nobody"

Comment: Congratulations! I confirm that nobody has answered this question on October 22, 2019. Nobody gets the green check. And now you may change back your display name to whatever you want, so that <it doesn't matter much in the end>.

Comment: But you are actually Samuel, not Nobody :P

Answer (score 9):

‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎

Comment: *squints* What is this sorcery... (+1)

Comment: This is amazing! Is this the first blank (well maybe spaces) answer that gets **upvoted**?! +1 :)

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the answer to the puzzle? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.

Comment: @Deusovi It's no need to explain :P

Comment: @Duck I think this answer also deserve a special badge like 'accepted answer with less than X characters' criteria :D

Answer (score 4):

> ### Here is my answer:
>
> ### Thank you for reading.

P.S.:

> Click edit

Comment: Alas, there is still rot13(n <obql> ryrzrag) there. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission.

Comment: D'oh! Well, worth a shot. :-)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan but I thought that rot13(vg qbrfa'g znggre gung zhpu va gur raq)

Answer (score 4):

This is just to throw a wrench in the plans.

What happens when there are two (or more) 'Nobody' who answer

Comment: Careful, the universe might implode!

Comment: I would be more happy to accept your answer, since this is not a new user account. But... Nobody answers the question earlier than you... Upvote nevertheless!